# Unable load XML file with UTF-8 BOM marker using MSXML6

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, msxml

I have an XML file which has UTF-8 BOM marker(`EF BB BF`) at the beginning.

It also contains `encoding` as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`.

I am trying to load this XML file using `IXMLDOMDocument::LoadXML` which fails to load this document. If I remove the BOM marker it works perfectly.

My **question** is it wrong to have the BOM marker in this case or is it a bug with MSXML (MSXML6 to be precise)?

Comment: Did you check this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109767/msxmls-loadxml-fails-to-load-even-well-formed-xml maybe helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`IXMLDOMDocument::loadXML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754585(v=vs.85).aspx) method expects a `BSTR`, which is UTF-16 encoded. See [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247708/en-us) for a discussion of the issue.

I suggest to use [`IXMLDOMDocument::load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762722(v=vs.85).aspx) instead, which has various overloads which don't require UTF-16.